# Non-commited changes not read by transaction with READ_UNCOMMITTED isolation level

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to test how the isolation level of a transaction affects behavior across transactions. When using Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED, I was expecting that a different transaction would be able to see any uncommitted changes, however, I cannot see the same.

In the code below, I execute `transactionA` first. While it initially waits for 10 seconds, I invoke `transactionB` which inserts a new entity and waits for 15 seconds before committing. By the time `transactionB` commits, `transactionA`'s wait time is finished. So my expectation is that when I try to fetch the entities from the DB in this method, I should be able to see the uncommitted entity persisted by `transactionB`. This is not happening (refer to output)

```java
@Transactional(rollbackFor = ApiException.class, isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
public void transactionA() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("---Txn:A--- " + "START");
    wait(10, "---Txn:A--- ");
    System.out.println("---Txn:A--- " + "WAIT ENDED");
    
    List<TestEntity> testEntities = testEntityDao.selectAll();
    System.out.println("---Txn:A--- " + "FETCHED ALL ENTITIES");
    for (TestEntity e : testEntities)
        System.out.println("---Txn:A--- " + "ENTITY " + e.getId() + "," + e.getName());
}

@Transactional(rollbackFor = ApiException.class, isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
public void transactionB() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("---Txn:B--- " + "START");
    
    TestEntity newEntity = new TestEntity();
    newEntity.setName("NEW ENTITY TXN_B");
    testEntityDao.insert(newEntity);
    System.out.println("---Txn:B--- " + "PERSISTED NEW ENTITY");
    
    wait(15, "---Txn:B--- ");
    System.out.println("---Txn:B--- " + "WAIT ENDED");
}
```

Output:

```
1---Txn:A--- START
2---Txn:B--- START
3---Txn:B--- PERSISTED NEW ENTITY
4---Txn:A--- WAIT ENDED
5---Txn:A--- FETCHED ALL ENTITIES
6---Txn:B--- WAIT ENDED
```

If any entities were fetched, they should have been printed after line 5 above. However, nothing is being fetched. Why could this be occurring?

Comment: Could you show how do you call those methods?

Comment: @zforgo I have two controllers exposed to invoke these methods. I call them manually

Comment: it's clear. Are those controllers are transactional? Switching isolation level only applies to newly started transactions. Both ```transactionA()``` and ```transactionB()``` have ```REQUIRED``` propagation option which appends to the existing transaction if exists, otherwise new transaction will be created.
So, are you sure those methods will create new transactions with the proper isolation level?

Comment: @zforgo The controllers do not have any `@Transactional` present. The methods I have mentioned in my question are directly invoked by the controllers. So, I am assuming that a new transaction is initiated on invoking `transactionA()` and `transactionB()`

Comment: Then try to display ```TransactionSynchronizationManager.getCurrentTransactionIsolationLevel()``` to determine which isolation level used.